# How do I C# String value remove full name dynamically

Tags: c#

I have C# String value with full name and address, what I need to remove full name dynamically and only keep physical address. After full name, address start with number. My out put should be "13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia".
If not possible what is the best solution.

This is my static C# code

```
 string txtLocation = "Mrs Andrews,Eaaaaa 13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia";
 string txtLocationUp =  txtLocation.Substring(18, txtLocation.Length - 18);
```

Comment: It would be great if you add few noted about  `Eaaaaa` what is this? will it be same for all your inputs? or how it is vary for different input?

Comment: Eaaaaa is surname. all the time different names.(mr/mrs/miss first name, middle name, surname)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will be perfectly possible and there will be incorrect matches. Best bet maybe look at using Regex and create a couple of pattern matches that can extract the data for you.

```
    string txtLocation = "Mrs Andrews,Eaaaaa 13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia";

    string pattern = @"(\d.*)";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match match = rgx.Match(txtLocation);


    if(match.Success)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0]);
    }

    //add more patterns here???
```

Comment: pls tell me, if name has middle name, can use your code?

Comment: In short yes, basically the regex pattern will look for the first instance of a digit in the sting and select everything from that digit to the end of the string regardless if there is spaces etc. It will not work if the first part of the address does not start with a digit (as the part before the digit would not be selected). It will not work if the name contains a digit as it will thin it's part of the address. It will not find anthing if there are no digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regex` to split the address based on `number` which is starting point of address.

```
string txtLocation = "Mrs Andrews,Eaaaaa 13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia";
string []txtLocationUp = Regex.Split(txtLocation, @"\D+").Where(x=>x != string.Empty).ToArray();

string address = txtLocation.Substring(txtLocation.IndexOf(txtLocationUp[0])).Trim();
```

Comment: you code out put number missing(13), only display Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia

Comment: what code is most used and efficient Rayno Jacobs or yours?

Comment: I guess both are same but my code is short(in lines) and more easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

`Substring` will not be a good option here since the number of characters in name may vary, if their will be a comma(`,`) always in between full name and address means you can make use of them by `.Split` method of the String class. Then your code will looks like this :

```
string txtLocation = "Mrs Andrews,Eaaaaa 13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia";
string txtLocationUp =  txtLocation.Split(',')[1];
// here you will get : Eaaaaa 13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia
// and Last name has to be removed  so Use substring here
string addressPart = txtLocationUp.Substring(txtLocation.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
// addressPart holds the required address
```

Actually the `.Split` method will give you an array, the first index will always be the name and the rest will be the address as you are looking for.

Their may be chances for getting wrong output using this code, that are:

- When their is more than one comma in the address area then you will get only partial address.
- If their is no comma to separate the name and address then also code fails

Their is possibility for Substring as well, but in a different way by using the `IndexOf` method which will get you the first index of the specific character, By adding `+1` to this will give you the starting position of the Substring, since you ware not specifying the number of characters the whole string comes after the comma will be returned. So use like this:

```
string txtLocationUp = txtLocation.Substring(txtLocation.IndexOf(',') + 1);
string addressPart = txtLocationUp.Substring(txtLocation.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

One more note I have to add here is about `Eaaaaa` what is that? I can update the answer if you give a generalized description a bout this part in the input, will it vary? or its a constant?

Comment: He doesn't want the Eaaaaa part

Comment: Your both code, still last name still there(Eaaaaa). How can I remove full name

Comment: Could you please take a look into the updates, you will get the required address in the variable `addressPart`

Answer (score 0):

you need to break the string into array, you have "," in your string  as separator.

```
string[] parts = txtLocation.Split(',');
txtLocationUp = parts[1];
```

may be this help..

Answer (score 0):

you can not do anything to separate a string without separator, or static length. it must has potential to cause error, and your address will become false-positive which should not be implemented.

i think you should handle it reasonably, first, you can try to find out how your txtLocation constructed.

if it is constructed by you, you should know the maximum length of it, try to pad to include space for txtLocation, or include the separator. then you can separate your name and address by rather static length (substring) or split( separator).

Answer (score 0):

The below regular expression code will split the name and place it as the first element of a string array, which can then be used to replace or remove the first name in the whole string.

```
string txtLocation = "Mrs Andrews,Eaaaaa 13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]");
        string[] txtLocationUp = regex.Split(txtLocation);
        string address = txtLocation.Replace(txtLocationUp[0], "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by this,

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string txtLocation = "Mrs Andrews,Eaaaaa 13 Oaawood Rd ABBANVALA 3021 VIC Australia";        
        string fullAddress = txtLocation.Substring(txtLocation.IndexOf(',') + 1);
        fullAddress =  fullAddress.Substring(fullAddress.IndexOf(' '));
        Console.WriteLine(fullAddress);
    }   
}
```

Find the fiddle for the same, https://dotnetfiddle.net/ksIicH